# Writing varible strings and time to a file

Tags: python

I am writing my first program in python (first program ever for that matter). It's a simple program that detects input (On my raspberry pi) from a door chime and counts the number of times it goes off and prints the number of times on the screen followed by the date and time the event occurs.

So now I want to refine the program a bit; my first thought was to write the data to a file for later reviewing. I have figured out how to have my program create and open a file and even write simple strings to it, but getting it to write the strings with the variable (x) to it and the the variable 'time.strftime' to it has me stumped...

Here's my code:

```
 # My first program
 # version 1.1
 # Goal is to write each motion event to a file

 import time 
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.IN)
# input = GPIO.input(24)

 #temp code so I don't have to keep walking to the sensor called in the line commented out above.
 a = int(raw_input("Enter a number"))

x = 0

while True:
    #if (GPIO.input(24)):

    #again temp code, just the 'if a>0:'
    if a>0:
            x += 1
            print "There have been %d motion events!" % (x)
            print "The last one was on: "
            print time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
            print

            # Open the file that will hold the history data
            #this is where I am stuck...
            with open('history.dat', 'a') as file:
                    file.write('motion event recorded at: %s \n') %time.strftime("%m")
                    file.close()
            #pause the program to prevent multiple counts on a single person triggering the chime - some folks are slow ;)
            time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python print works in a different fashion.

Try this:

```
print("There have been"+ str(x) +"motion events!")
```

And this:

```
file.write('motion event recorded at: '+time.strftime("%m")+'\n')
```

Try posting what error you're receiving so that it's easier for people to answer.

Also, for a first time code, this is pretty good.

Comment: Well I'm glad things worked out. If this answer was indeed helpful, please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, you're help is very appreciated. I also figured out how to add the counter to the file based on your example. Here's what I did:

    file.write(str(x))
    file.write(' motion event recorded at: '+time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")+'\n')

Comment: Why isn't my code the my above comment showing right?

Comment: So actually you could simply write this `file.write(str(x)+" - "+"Motion event recorded at: "+time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")+'\n')`. Also, to show code, use the symbol above tilde(~) around the code block.

Comment: Cool! Thanks again, yeah, I was trying to make it all happen in the one line, but I was not able to figure it out. Once I got it to work the way I did, I tapped out! I'll be changing it to the way you just showed me though, since it's probably a 'cleaner' way to do it.

Again, thanks!